# Python logging threadName and multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a program that uses multiprocessing.Process object to spin off chunks of the program. I'm passing it a configured logger with the following formatter

```
formatter = logging.Formatter( '[%(created)s] [%(threadName)s] %(message)s')
```

I create the process similar to this

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(
            name='abc',
            target=target_function,
            args=(log)
            )
```

This logs messages in both the main process and the children as the following

```
[1412095772.77] [MainThread] Hello World from main process
[1412095772.77] [MainThread] Hello World from child process
```

My understanding is that threadName should be using 'abc' from above and not MainThread again.

Does anyone know why it appears as if it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Formatter` using the name of the *thread* it's running in. In both the parent and child process, the active thread is `MainThread`, because each process is running a single thread. It sounds like you really want the *process* name to be printed, not the thread name:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter( '[%(created)s] [%(processName)s] %(message)s')
```

Comment: I should have just tried processName, but when it wasn't listed in the docs, I just blanked on it. Thanks!

Comment: @kormac It's actually [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). Glad it worked for you in any case.